# Providing custom spacing in a .bib annotation

Tags: bibtex

I'm creating an annotated bibliography (in IEEE style), and the annotations are required to be formatted in a specific format: left-aligned, every paragraph should be indented. I don't have time to write a custom formatter for any type of paper/journal, so I combined the latest `IEEEtran.bst` and [IEEEannot](https://www.barik.net/sw/ieee/) by Titus Barik into `mystyle.bst`.

The problem is that I can't add extra spacing into the annote field, I've tried various combinations of `\hspace`, `~`, `\` , `\indent`, which seem to only delete the next word.

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{mystyle}
\bibliography{annot}
\end{document}
```

A short example from `annot.bib`, indentation doesn't work in the `annote` part:

```
@INBOOK{6284438,
  author={S. {Ullman}},
  booktitle={{The Interpretation of Visual Motion}}, 
  title={{The Interpretation of Structure from Motion}}, 
  year={1979},
  volume={},
  number={},
  pages={133-175},
  keywords={},
  doi={},
  ISSN={},
  publisher={MITP},
  isbn={9780262257121},
  url={https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6284438},
  annote = {
    This paragraph is indented via the style file
    \newline This works, but not indented
    \newline ~~~~This doesn't work
  }
}
```

An excerpt from `mystyle.bst`, indentation using `~` works here (and it's obviously applied only to the first paragraph of an annotation):

```
% annotation addition
FUNCTION {format.annotate}
{ annote empty$
    { "" }
    { "\begin{flushleft}~~~~~~~~"
        annote
        * "\end{flushleft}" *
    }
    if$
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that asterisk commands are not being ignored, so the solution is to add the following, where appropriate:

```
\hspace*{1em}
```